# Need to update ssis connection manager for almost 1000 packages

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

My team is updating their SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016, and thus we must update our Visual Studio (2012) SSIS/Data Tools package connections to use SQL Server 2016.

Currently the plan is to do this one by one!

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a config file to set the DB connection.

The Connection Manager name needs to be the same though.

This allows you to run the same package in different environments as well. So you can have a config file for DEV, TEST and PROD.

We configure DB conn and file paths for each environment.

Comment: Excellent.  This is what we SHOULD have used from the beginning.  But is it possible to use this config file without making changes to ALL my Packages?

Comment: Yes. I assume you run packages from agent? Agent allow you to specify a config file.

Comment: Our ssis flow is this... we use config to set db conn and 2 variables connStr and filePath. And in all other packages we configure based on parent variables. This will take work to set up but works really well.

Comment: I cant seem to edit from phone. The config file is only used for master package which runs maintenance sql and runs all sub packages.